# Flask sessions in memcached/Couchbase; are they safe?

Tags: python, session, flask, couchbase

Currently running several Flask websites under IIS/Windows 2008 Server, we need to implement sessions and application scope storage.
I was checking out the possibilities for Sessions in Flask, and running on Windows 2008 more or less rules out [Redis](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis#known-issues) as a viable storage option (I know there is a Windows port, but it seems not quite mature yet).

The next best option seems to be memcached. There is a very nice looking implementation for Windows in the form of [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-server), but we have some concerns/questions;

1. What happens if there is too much data in the sessions, and the available memory is full, will memcached just start deleting older    (but maybe still legitimate) session data?
2. If so, is there a solution in Couchbase/memcached to prevent this?
3. On the couchbase homepage it says it's possible to install couchbase [as a key/value store](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-server#overview) as well. Could this be a better option for storing session data, or would it have the same problems as installing Couchbase as a memcache compatible storage?

Comment: I think memcache is typically used for caching data; I'd use redis here as a key/value store for session data. In either case; if you start to run out of working memory I know of no database that will just start randomly deleting old data :)

Comment: Hi @JamesMills, that's my point. It is a caching engine in principle, so it will have data go stale if it's not being used frequently. Stale data gets deleted from cache in order to make room for more heavily used data if I understand correctly. So this might cause memcached to delete active sessions if there's lots of activity.

Comment: That's certainly quite possible depending on configuration; which is why I *recommend* use use an actual key/value store like Redis :)

Comment: From the Couchbase point of view it depends which bucket type you use. If you use a memcached bucket it will behave like memcached. If you the couchbase bucket then once memory is filled it will eject items that have been persistent to disk already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of Couchbase Server:

> 1. What happens if there is too much data in the sessions, and the available memory is full, will memcached just start deleting older (but maybe still legitimate) session data?

Yes - `memcached` is a *cache* - you specify a memory quota and that amount of RAM is used to cache items. When you fill that amount up it will eject (i.e. delete) old items. This is standard caching behaviour.

> 2. If so, is there a solution in Couchbase/memcached to prevent this?
> 3. On the couchbase homepage it says it's possible to install couchbase as a key/value store as well. Could this be a better option for storing session data, or would it have the same problems as installing Couchbase as a memcache compatible storage?

For memcached - not really - that's the whole point of it.

For Couchbase Server - yes. In addition to the *memcache*-type bucket, Couchbase Server also has a *Couchbase* bucket type. This has a memory quota which is used to keep recently-used items in, but all items are *persisted* to disk. If an item isn't available in memory then it will fetch it from disk.